# Am I using cython in the right way?

Tags: python, cython

I've been converting to cython some python functions and classes in a project I'm developing. So now I have various .pyx files and corresponding .py files which contain basically the same code, the cython ones including types for variables. But also, from time to time, the cython ones include some small modifications from the python code—(1) because the modified code is faster (but equivalent) that way than keeping the same python form.

At the beginning I didn't think this duplicity of code would be a problem. In addition, I was planing to compare the outputs of the python and cython implementations regularly so that I could pick up faster any unintended modification to one or the other. The problem is that I have more work to keep both implementations in sync, as I find bugs, make improvements, etc. And this makes me wonder if this is the right way of using cython.

I know that ideally you would do all your project in python and then if it's slow, find hot spots and cythonize these. However, in my project, I'm using python as a matlab substitute to interactively prototype algorithms in an augmented reality system that I'm developing. The system works in realtime, so I often cython the new algorithms early on to get higher fps and see how it behaves in realtime.

So my questions:

Do projects that involve a lot of cython code have duplicated code? .pyx files and corresponding .py files? and keep them in sync? or do they only use cython and develop new algorithms directly in cython? then there wouldn't be duplicated code. However, I can't debug cython code in my favourite python IDE (wingIDE). For that matter, I have never managed to get cygdb working in Windows 7 (after trying for a long while I think it only works in linux) so I'm stuck with debugging cython code with print statements, which is not ideal, and basically I loose all the interactive development (matlab like) I can do with python and wingIDE.

Then there is pure python mode http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/pure.html I like the idea of using a .pxd file to augment my python code, then I wouldn't have the duplicated code problem. I haven't tried it yet, but I have read about of some limitations, so I'm not sure if it's working well enough. Also, I don't know if with pure python mode I could integrate these small modifications from the python code that I talk about above in (1). Could these go in a pxd file? or would I then have to have a pxy file for the modification? or better forget about modify anything.  Has anybody had good experiences with pure python mode?

I don't know if there is another better way of using cython, so please, if you know a better way let us know.

Comment: I don't understand: why do you "lose all the interactive development"? When you `cpdef` functions, you can play with them in ipython ... You can make a tiny `.pyx` file to test code snippets ... What exactly are you missing? Just the debugger?

Comment: Yes. When I mean "interactive development" I mean to write code and test it while you are stopped in a breakpoint, having access to all the stack frames. WingIDE debugger allows that, and that's the closest I found in the python world to develop as I use to in matlab. I have tried ipython but I couldn't emulate this type of devloping with it.

Comment: There is at least one valid argument for maintaining both a Python, as well as a Cython version: tests. A simple implementation in Python can be used to validate the results of a Cython version, on small problem instances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: no, python projects don't keep both the cython and the python code. It is too much burden to maitain both.

Here is how I use cython: I start by implementing the code in Python. Usually, I test on small datasets, so the speed is not an issue. If I see that the code is too slow, I try finding optimization in Python. If I can't find any, I try cythonizing the code. Once this is done, I compare the python implementation and the cython one in terms of speed ups (with ipython's %timeit magic function).

Indeed, the cython code is more complicated to debug than the python one. But usually, I start writing the cython code, I have a bug free algorithms. Also, the traceback contains the line number of the cython code that raised the exception. If your code segfaults, you can try using gdb to debug it [1]_

I have yet to use pxd files.

[1]_ http://scipy-lectures.github.com/advanced/debugging/index.html#debugging-segmentation-faults-using-gdb

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it will be a problem for me to have only the cython files as I would probably be changing that code every time I try a new technique for a subsystem. Then I would need to convert it back to python again for debugging. Debugging new code in cython would nill the reason why I'm using python to do my research and not do it directly in C++. I use datasets to test the algorithms, but I also want to see them working live video (as I'm developing an interactive system).

Comment: @NelleV: Statistically, residual errors always remain in any piece of code, be it Python or Cython. Trust in a Python implementation does not imply the correctness of a Cython version derived from it (unless the Cython version is identical, i.e., pure Python).

Comment: @martinako: Writing Cython directly is premature optimization, unless it is impossible to perform any meaningful development for that particular field in Python. Experiments are supposed to be developed in Python, and only selected, well-established core parts pushed down to a lower level. A profiler can help to decide which parts.